# How to preserve data format same as dataframe in excel?

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, date, date-format

I have customised my dataframe date format to %d%m%Y. When I export as CSV and I opened the file instead of showing date format as 06/07/2023 it is showing 6/7/2023. How can I fix that.

When I export as text editor it is not changing the format.

When I read the output CSV in python and print the dataframe can see format is not changed in python . But in excel it is changed.

I have tried using date_format as parameter while exporting to csv

Comment: CSV and Excel are not synonyms. If you need formatting, then create an Excel file. Otherwise, *import* the CSV file into Excel, and specify that particular column as text, or apply a particular date format. Note that *importing* is *not* the same as opening.